# Каким образом я могу объеденить два словаря?

Tags: python, python-3.x

имеется список словарей такого вида:

```
[
    {'id': 1, 'title': 'Yummy', 'description': 'be taste', 'survey_id': 1, 'q': 'How long?', 'visible': True, 'max_points': 2.0, 'poll_id': 1, 'text': 'very long', 'question_id': 1}, 
    {'id': 2, 'title': 'Yummy', 'description': 'be taste', 'survey_id': 1, 'q': 'How long?', 'visible': True, 'max_points': 2.0, 'poll_id': 1, 'text': 'not longer long', 'question_id': 1}
]
```

Суть в том что это один объект, но при создании в бд, создается два объекта. Мне необходимо из этих двух объектов создать один словарь, похожего вида:

```
{
    "title": "Yummy",
    "description": "be taste",
    "survey_id": null,
    "id": 1,
    "questions": [
      {
        "q": "How long?",
        "visible": true,
        "max_points": 2,
        "answers": [
          {
            "text": "very long"
          },
          {
            "text": "not longer long"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Основное отличие это группировка нескольких text из двух объектов в список словарей answers.
Буду очень благодарен, за подсказки и идеи, даже не само решение.

Comment: даю "подсказку и идею": пересмотрите структуру бд и селектов из нее, раз у вас такие словари выходят

Comment: какой "id" должен быть в результирующем словаре? первый? а в списке все одинаковые словари, кроме полей "id" и "text"?